# Ошибка KeyError при запуске кода в Python 3

Tags: python

Нижеприведенный код - для Python 3. Во время запуска кода возникает ошибка (ругается) на строку "**if country['visa']:**". Примерно в чем ошибка понимаю, но как исправить - ума не приложу.

Как конкретно (до символа) изменить код, чтобы на выходе получалось - какие страны только с морем, какие только с шенгеном, у каких стран есть и шенген и море, а также сколько у меня будет денег в местной валюте при условных 10000 денег.

```
countries = [
    {'name': 'Thailand', 'sea': True, 'visa': False, 'average_temperature': 30},
        {'currency_rate': 1.8},
    {'name': 'Hungary', 'sea': False, 'visa': True, 'average_temperature': 10},
        {'currency_rate': 0.3},
    {'name': 'Germany', 'sea': True, 'visa': True, 'average_temperature': 5},
        {'currency_rate': 80},
    {'name': 'Japan', 'sea': True, 'visa': False, 'average_temperature': 15},
        {'currency_rate': 0.61},
    ]

visa_countries = set()
sea_countries = set()

for country in countries:
    if country['visa']:
        visa_countries.add(country['name'])
    if country['sea']:
        sea_countries.add(country['name'])


print (sea_countries)
print (visa_countries)
print ('Страны в шенгене и с морем: ', visa_countries & sea_countries)


money_amount = 10000
for country in countries:
    print('У нас будет %.3f денег в местной валюте' % currency_amount)


sea_visa_countries = visa_countries & sea_countries

for country_name in sea_visa_countries:
    for country in countries:
        if country ['name'] == country_name:
            print (country)
            break
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: У вас в списке countries есть словари, в которых нет ключа 'visa' (например словари с currency_rate - это отдельные словари, никак не относящиеся к предыдущим строкам)

Comment: Подозреваю, что у вас должно было быть всего четыре словаря, но каждый из них ошибочно оказался разбит на два.

Comment: Может словарь просто заболел))

Answer (score 2):

данные по рейтингу включите внутрь словаря про страну.
Ваш цикл ищет по всем словарям списка стран, а в словаре содержащем только ключ `currency_rate` про визу ничего нет...

Comment: Василь (Василий), Вы оказались правы. Именно это и следовало сделать! Помогло!))